# macCatalyst app builds but won't launch on Mac

Tags: swiftui, catalyst, viewmodifier

I am designing a swiftUi app which runs seamlessly on iOS 14 simulators and devices, but fails to launch on the Mac (10.15.7).
The app builds without issues, then I have this in the console:

dyld: Symbol not found: _$s7SwiftUI20_ValueActionModifierVMn
Referenced from: /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gzynpflipftikkauzulvrrrxaniv/Build/Products/Debug-maccatalyst/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp (which was built for Mac OS X 14.0)

Expected in: /System/iOSSupport/System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/Versions/A/SwiftUI
in /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gzynpflipftikkauzulvrrrxaniv/Build/Products/Debug-maccatalyst/myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp
(lldb)

Any idea of what this refers to?
Thanx!